# Piping delays output to file from loop in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, append, pipe, io-redirection

In a Bash loop, I have a mix of commands that append directly to a file, and commands that output to stdout, and then the whole loop is appended to the same file, like this:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    echo foo >> mylog
    echo bar
done >> mylog
```

The result is that the lines in the `mylog` file are interleaved, as if the output from the `echo bar` is appended to `mylog` in real time:

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

However, if I pipe the output of the loop through any command (I use the trivial `cat` command here for simplicity, but it could be any other command where I take each input line and output a processed line), and then pipe it to the file, like this:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    echo foo >> mylog
    echo bar
done | cat >> mylog
```

the output is not interleaved, with all the `bar`s printed after all the `foo`s, as if it waited until all the output was done from the `cat` before appending the lines to the file:

```
foo
foo
foo
bar
bar
bar
```

My questions are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I modify my second code (assuming I still want to have each line processed through a custom command) so that the output is interleaved?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happens:

loop repeat 3 times:

- `echo foo >> mylog`: Open file `mylog`, append `foo`, close file `mylog`.
- `echo bar`: Append `bar` to the already opened `stdout` file handle.

whole loop as a single block:

- `done |`: redirect the whole `stdout` for the loop to the pipe which has a small buffer for until the receiving process is ready to listen and read `stdin` data from the pipe.
- `cat >> mylog`: The sub-process running the cat command, open file `mylog`, append what has been read from `stdin`, close file `mylog`.

Technically it is:

Repeat 3 times:

- Inefficiently append `foo` to `mylog`.
- Append `bar` to buffer.

Content of `mylog` at this stage:

```
foo
foo
foo
```

Then:

- Read buffer content and append it all to `mylog`

Content of `mylog` at this stage:

```
foo
foo
foo
bar
bar
bar
```

If more content was generated in the loop, it would probably block or interleave content once the `cat` sub-process starts appending concurrently to the file.

Comment: Is there a way to unbuffer it?

Comment: @user102008, no. Could you explain user intent by updating your question? What are you trying to do?